# Rails 6 jbuilder not rendering array properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem with rendering array properly with JBuilder on Rails 6 (API only mode).

I basically have a list of registration plates, which I want to fetch via API request

My index view looks like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

json.array! @registration_plates,
            partial: 'registration_plates/registration_plate',
            as: :registration_plate
```

My show view looks like:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

json.partial! 'registration_plates/registration_plate',
              registration_plate: @registration_plate
```

And finally partial `_registration_plate.json.jbuilder` is very simple:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

json.id registration_plate.id
json.plate registration_plate.plate.to_s
```

I do get a normal response from server: 
[image: response]

But instead of an array, I get the series of JSON objects

[image: postman]

Did anyone have similar problem, or do you have any idea how to solve it?

Than you in advance.

**EDIT**

Also my controller is configured to render the jbuilder rather than json

```
  # GET /registration_plates
  def index
    @registration_plates = RegistrationPlate.all

    render @registration_plates
  end

  # GET /registration_plates/1
  def show
    render @registration_plate
  end
```

And if I change the index action to look like

```
  def index
    @registration_plates = RegistrationPlate.all

    render json: @registration_plates.to_json(only: %i[id plate])
  end
```

i do get correct output, but then, I defy the sole purpose of jbuilder

Comment: can you try one thing... remove `render @registration_plates` from your `index` action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your index to remove `render @registration_plates`

```
  # GET /registration_plates
  def index
    @registration_plates = RegistrationPlate.all
  end
```

`render @registration_plates` renders `_registration_plate.json.jbuilder` directly without going into `index.json.jbuilder`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Happy to help!!